# scons strips drive letter from CPPINCFLAGS

Tags: python, c++, scons

I've been creating a SConstruct file for the arm-none-eabi-gcc toolchain.

I have a list of include search paths being added to the environment like so:

```
env.Append(CPPPATH = 
[
    '#' + os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'thirdparty','cmsis','inc'),
    '#' + os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'thirdparty','cmsis','dev','ST','STM32F3xx','inc'),
    '#' + os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'thirdparty','hal','inc'),
    '#' + os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'thirdparty','hal','inc','legacy')
])
```

I expect any `-I` options to have the form e.g. `-ID:\Code\stm32blinky\thirdparty\hal\inc`

However, What Scons converts these paths is e.g.

`-ICode\stm32blinky\thirdparty\hal\inc`

Causing the compilation to fail.

So somewhere along the way, the drive letter is being dropped.

Printing `env['CPPPATH']` yields the output:

```
[
    '#D:\\Code\\stm32blinky\\thirdparty\\cmsis\\inc',
    '#D:\\Code\\stm32blinky\\thirdparty\\cmsis\\dev\\ST\\STM32F3xx\\inc',    
    '#D:\\Code\\stm32blinky\\thirdparty\\hal\\inc',     
    '#D:\\Code\\stm32blinky\\thirdparty\\hal\\inc\\legacy'
]
```

So I'm guessing that this happens when Scons generates the $_CPPINCFLAGS variable from the $CPPPATH variable.

What in Scons decides how the CPPPATH entries are rendered?

Comment: This looks like an XY problem to me. Can you please specify in which absolute path your top-level SConstruct is? My guess is: `D:\Code\stm32blinky`, is that correct? Have you tried `#thirdparty\\cmsis\\inc` for the `CPPPATH` instead?

Comment: That is correct. No, I haven't as I wanted to keep the whole thing portable between OSes.

Comment: But you can leave out the `os.getcwd()` then, right? Please try and see if this works...

Comment: I can, and I've figured it out. The compilation error was actually unrelated to how scons modifies the search paths. I think this is a non-issue.